# Wall Framing Question

Tags: bathroom, framing, carpentry, renovation

currently renovating 1st floor bathroom, behind the tub wall was a layer of tile/sheetrock, old wood siding, and underneath the siding is 2 layers of vertical 1x8 lumber. There is no 2x4 framing in this wall, and it separates the end of our living room and this bathroom. These double layered planks are sitting on a concrete foundation, so I imagine they have to be structural, however can't understand how they could be carrying the load of the 2nd story above. When I renovated one of our upstairs bedrooms, it was all plaster and lathe, with 2x4 framing on 3 of the 4 walls. There was one wall in this upstairs bedroom that also had this double layer board construction. Does anyone know what this is called? I can't find any information and now I'm trying to fur our the bathroom shower wall so I can level it before tiling. Don't have enough room to build a 2x4 or 1x4 wall in front of these planks because it will change the layout of toilet/ and other plumbing fixtures.

Comment: Photos or plans would help

Comment: Most inside walls are not structural/load bearing.  As long as they stand up, they main purpose is to hold the finish surface of the wall, and maybe to hide plumbing/electrical runs.  Pictures will help a lot.

Comment: @crip659: Heavy emphasis on "most", though.